# Remove duplicates from combined arrays

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, duplicates, combinations

My aim to create multiple possible of out comes with 3 arrays.

I achieved it but I got struck with one problem.

I find there is repeated values with different keys.

below is the code I tried to generate.

```
$top = array(array('toplinner_name' => M1), array('toplinner_name' => M2));
$flute1 = array(array('f1_name' => M3));
$single_array = compares($top, $flute1); //combaining arrays
$bottom = array(array('bottomlinner_name' => M1), array('bottomlinner_name' => M2));
$single_array = compares($single_array, $bottom); //combaining arrays

function compares($a, $b) {
    if (is_array($a) && is_array($b)) {
        if (count($a) < count($b)) {
            list($a, $b) = array($b, $a);
        }
        $new = array();
        $k = 0;
        for ($i = 0; $i < count($b); $i++) {
            for ($j = 0; $j < count($a); $j++) {
                $new[$k] = array_merge($b[$i], $a[$j]);
                $k++;
            }
        }
        return $new;
    }
    return null;
}
```

with the above code I am getting out put as

```
Array{
     '0'=>{'toplinner_name'=>'M1','f1_name'=>'M3','bottomlinner_name'=>'M1'},
     '2'=>{'toplinner_name'=>'M1','f1_name'=>'M3','bottomlinner_name'=>'M2'},
     '3'=>{'toplinner_name'=>'M2','f1_name'=>'M3','bottomlinner_name'=>'M1'},
     '4'=>{'toplinner_name'=>'M2','f1_name'=>'M3','bottomlinner_name'=>'M2'},
  }
```

As you can see from the above out put 2 and 3 are same linners so I need t0 consider them as one how can I remove those duplicate values.....
I tried below code

```
$input = array_map("unserialize", array_unique(array_map("serialize", $new)));
```

but it gives me same out put.

my desired out put should be

```
Array{
     '0'=>{'toplinner_name'=>'M1','f1_name'=>'M3','bottomlinner_name'=>'M1'},
     '1'=>{'toplinner_name'=>'M1','f1_name'=>'M3','bottomlinner_name'=>'M2'},
     '2'=>{'toplinner_name'=>'M2','f1_name'=>'M3','bottomlinner_name'=>'M2'},
  }
```

Comment: Have you tried with only: `$input = array_unique($new);` ?

Comment: with that iam getting error "Notice:  Array to string conversion "

Comment: You should use the flag `SORT_REGULAR` like this: `$input = array_unique($new, SORT_REGULAR);`

Comment: it working but my desired out put is coming.it gives me same out put

Comment: this will return u two records as [{"toplinner_name":"M1","f1_name":"M3","bottomlinner_name":"M1"},{"toplinner_name":"M1","f1_name":"M3","bottomlinner_name":"M2"}]

Comment: see this link http://183.82.112.177/nick_samples/newalgo/

Comment: Please show me your exact output. you want output like this : Array{
     '0'=>{'toplinner_name'=>'M1','f1_name'=>'M3','bottomlinner_name'=>'M1'},
     '2'=>{'toplinner_name'=>'M2','f1_name'=>'M3','bottomlinner_name'=>'M2'},
  }
 Value of bottomlinner_name can be either M1 or M2 does not matter. Right ?

Comment: check my question in that my exact out put is also present

Answer (score 0):

Example with your mentioned array in comments:

```
<?

// your array
$res[]=array('toplinner_name'=>'M1','f1_name'=>'M3','bottomlinner_name'=>'M1');
$res[]=array('toplinner_name'=>'M1','f1_name'=>'M3','bottomlinner_name'=>'M2');
$res[]=array('toplinner_name'=>'M1','f1_name'=>'M3','bottomlinner_name'=>'M1');
$res[]=array('toplinner_name'=>'M1','f1_name'=>'M3','bottomlinner_name'=>'M2');

// remove duplicates by using array_map and array_unique for multidimensional array
$duplicateRemoved = array_map("unserialize", array_unique(array_map("serialize", $res)));

// rearrange the array
$rearrangeArray = array_values($duplicateRemoved);

// encode the unique array into json format    
$encodedData = json_encode($rearrangeArray);

// print result    
echo $encodedData;    

?>
```

Comment: the above code will work if keys are same but my keys are diffrent

Comment: i just added my desire out put in my question check once

Comment: @sasikanth: i have tested with 0,2,3,4 indexes its works same

Comment: @sasikanth: because all values are different. so u will get the all values.. u want to remove index no 3

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102205/discussion-between-sasi-kanth-and-devpro).

Comment: @devpro shall this question be closed as Unclear?

Answer (score 0):

Those lines are different, see in bold:

'0'=>{'t'=>'M**1**','f'=>'M3','b'=>'M**1**'},

'2'=>{'t'=>'M1','f'=>'M3','b'=>'M**2**'},

'3'=>{'t'=>'M**2**','f'=>'M3','b'=>'M**1**'},

'4'=>{'t'=>'M2','f'=>'M3','b'=>'M**2**'},

Comment: i need to show either 2 or 1 not both . i just added my desire out in question check once

Comment: I don't get it. What about `'4'=>{'t'=>'M2','f'=>'M3','b'=>'M2'},` ? it's different from all the other lines in either t, or b or both. Can you explain again what exactly do you want? Not just by the expected output but by explaining why

Comment: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102205/discussion-between-sasi-kanth-and-devpro...check this

Comment: @Gav shall this page be closed as Unclear?